# How different in meaning of fulfilling and rewarding?

Tags: american-english

Do this 2 sentences carry the same meaning?
1. I find this job very fulfilling.
2. I find this job very rewarding.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are synonyms, but suggest slightly different things. Both words suggest that you have received mental satisfaction from doing something, but only because you have done it, not because of the effects or consequences of the act itself. Sometimes, "rewarding" can mean satisfaction from the effects of the action in addition to a direct mental satisfaction, though. Now, let's look at each word. "Fulfilling" suggests that the action has satisfied you because it completed a long-term desire. You would probably do something that is fulfilling often, or continually, because it satisfies a craving for "purpose." For example, volunteering at you church can be fulfilling. "Rewarding" suggests that the satisfaction you receive is beneficial to an aspect of your life. It is often more short-term and less "deep." For example, chatting with a more experienced professional in your industry is rewarding because you gain knowledge and perhaps useful skills. Donating money to a charity is rewarding because it make you feel great short term. Donating wouldn't really be fulfilling, right? Its more surface-level. "Fulfilling" is usually a larger investment on your part, for a deeper reward, when compared to "rewarding." The dictionary says something that is "fulfilling" may develop your character. Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for the good use of *donating* to distinguish the senses of the two terms.